# Using RSAPrivateKey (and not RSAPrivateCrtKey) to save an RSA private key to Android KeyStore

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa, keystore

I'm developing an application which implements an RSA [threshold signature](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-387-23483-7_429) between a server and an Android app.

The server and app each have a share of the RSA private key. In Android/Java, there are two classes for holding an RSA private key:

1. [RSAPrivateKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey)
2. [RSAPrivateCrtKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey)

The latter holds extra information (such as the factorization of modulus, [CRT coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm), etc.) to improve the efficiency of signing. However, I can't store the extra info as they leak the master private key.

I tried storing an object of the former type (`RSAPrivateKey`) in Android KeyStore, but it seems the key store accepts only the latter type (`RSAPrivateCrtKey`).

Here's the code excerpt that works ([DummyCert](https://pastebin.com/raw/RXsSb2P9) is just an implementation of `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` whose all methods return the default value):

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger d = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger e = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger primeP = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger primeQ = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger primeExponentP = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger primeExponentQ = new BigInteger("...");
BigInteger crt = new BigInteger("...");

KeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(n, e, d, primeP, primeQ, primeExponentP, primeExponentQ, crt);

KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey sk = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

Certificate[] dummy = new Certificate[]{new DummyCert()};

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
keyStore.setKeyEntry(KEY_ALIAS, sk, null, dummy);
```

However, if we change the definition of `keySpec` to:

```
KeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(n, d);
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:04000090:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:VALUE_MISSING
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_marshal_private_key(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey.getEncoded(OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey.java:207)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.setPrivateKeyEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:480)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineSetKeyEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:294)
    at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1179)
    at com.example.keystoretester.MainActivity.createKeyStoreEntry(MainActivity.java:68)
    at com.example.keystoretester.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

---

**PS:**

I traced the code for `setKeyEntry` line by line. It seems that the exception is thrown by this section of `AndroidKeyStoreSpi` that probably calls a *native* function:

```
int errorCode = mKeyStore.importKey(
        Credentials.USER_PRIVATE_KEY + alias,
        importArgs,
        KeymasterDefs.KM_KEY_FORMAT_PKCS8,
        pkcs8EncodedPrivateKeyBytes,
        mUid,
        flags,
        resultingKeyCharacteristics);
if (errorCode != KeyStore.NO_ERROR) {
    throw new KeyStoreException("Failed to store private key",
            KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(errorCode));
}
```

It might be possible to circumvent the above check by directly accessing the key store service. One such example is explained [here](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-keystore). But the code is for Android 4.x, which is probably too old. I just wanted to get an expert opinion before digging any further.

Comment: You're basically want to demarshal everything. `previousPrime()` or `previousProbablePrime()` is one method that you need. That's all I can say.

Comment: *...However, I can't store the extra info as they leak the master private key....* I don't know what this means exactly but given just the private exponent (and the public exponent and modulus) you can quickly derive all the remaining parameters present in the CRT form of the private key. So, effectively, anything leaked in `RSAPrivateCrtKey` is also leaked in `RSAPrivateKey`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: That's exactly why I don't store the public exponent along with the private key, and use the DummyCert class. To be exact, let (e,n) be the public key and (d,n) the private key. Two private key shares are extracted (d1, n) and (d2, n), with d1*d2 = d (mod phi(n)). The app stores only (d1, n), but **not** its "corresponding" public key (e1, n) with e1 = (d1)^-1 mod phi(n).

Answer (score 0):

A more modern interface is provided by [KeyProtection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.html), you might want to try that.

`EVP_marshal_private_key` takes a PrivateKeyInfo structure, so it should technically work with different formats of keys. Looking at the code for [OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/dac92c6/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey.java), it looks like n and should be enough, so maybe there is a problem with your key format?

The low-level API has changed a lot and is not officially supported, so I don't really recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried incorporating the KeyProtection class into my code. [Here](https://github.com/msdousti/AndroidKeyStoreTester) is the result. Unfortunately, if you change `crtKey` to `false` [in this line of code](https://github.com/msdousti/AndroidKeyStoreTester/blob/d2325967af756bae82b5f073097ba84f92f006af/app/src/main/java/com/example/keystoretester/MainActivity.java#L55), you'll get the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, have you tried on different Android versions and devices/emulator?

Comment: I also faced with the same issue that @M.S.Dousti mentioned is his question & tried his solution on different devices with different api level (both on physical device/emulator) as Nikolay suggeted but I got error. One thing about the error that might give you a clue is that when I ran the sample on a device with api level 29, I got OPENSSL_internal:VALUE_MISSING ... same as the error M.S. Dousti reported, but when I ran the sample on a device with api level 23 I got java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to store private key
android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob error

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidKeyStore` seems to only accept RSA private keys that is *readily encodable* into ASN.1 format as defined in [RFC 3447](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3447#appendix-A.1). This limitation is inherited from the underlying `Keymaster` which guarantees to accept RSA private keys that are already encoded this way, judging from the public test cases in AOSP source code so far.

This means that you need to disclose the prime factors if you ever what to import RSA keys into the Keystore.

Comment: This is true when using the Java API. But the question is, can I directly talk to the keystore service? See the example link at the end of the question.